# How to join additional table when left outer not working

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing proc which I have chopped up for brevity's sake

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
    col1, col2
    SELECT col3--aggregate columns
    FROM iep i
        INNER JOIN student s ON s.studentID = i.studentID
        INNER JOIN dbo.IDuration id ON i.IepID = id.iepID
        INNER JOIN AppointmentStudent as ON s.studentID = as.studentID
        INNER JOIN Appointment a ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
        INNER JOIN AppointmentTherapist at ON a.appointmentID = at.appointmentID
    WHERE s.studentID = @studentID
    GROUP BY  col1, col2
    ) t
```

The aggregate columns summarizes appointments into the weeks of the year, but it only does sos for the weeks the student had appointments. I have an additional table called SchoolWeekYear that is populated with all of the weeks of the year that I am trying to integrate to this proc so I get 52 records back and not just the handful I am currently getting.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
    col1, col2
    SELECT col3--aggregate columns
    FROM iep i
        INNER JOIN student s ON s.studentID = i.studentID
        INNER JOIN dbo.IDuration id ON i.IepID = id.iepID
        INNER JOIN AppointmentStudent as ON s.studentID = as.studentID
        INNER JOIN Appointment a ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SchoolWeekYear swy on a.calWeekNumber = swy.calWeekNumber
        INNER JOIN AppointmentTherapist at ON a.appointmentID = at.appointmentID
    WHERE s.studentID = @studentID
    GROUP BY  col1, col2
    ) t
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Certainly possible. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to integrate `SchoolWeekYear` into the existing table set at an earlier stage.

To show you the principle, let us simplify the problem even further. Let there be a table called `WeeklyData` with columns `WeekNumber` and `SomeData`. Some weeks might have multiple entries, some others none. So this query

```
SELECT
  WeekNumber,
  AGG(SomeData)
FROM
  WeeklyData
GROUP BY
  WeekNumber
;
```

would return only weeks present in `WeeklyData`. If you want to return data for all weeks, use a corresponding reference table (let it be called `AllWeeks`) like this:

```
SELECT
  aw.WeekNumber,
  AGG(wd.SomeData)
FROM
  AllWeeks AS aw
LEFT JOIN
  WeeklyData AS wd ON aw.WeekNumber = wd.WeekNumber
GROUP BY
  aw.WeekNumber
;
```

So, you take the reference table (`AllWeeks`) and join the data table (`WeeklyData`) *to it*, not the other round.

Now, what if the original query was slightly more complex? Let us now suppose the data table is called `StudentWeeklyData` and has a column called `StudentID` which is a reference to a `Students` table. Let us also imagine the query is similar to yours in that it logically includes the `Students` table before the data table is joined and filters the results on the primary key of `Students`:

```
SELECT
  s.StudentID,
  s.StudentName,
  swd.WeekNumber,
  AGG(swd.SomeData)
FROM
  Students AS s
INNER JOIN
  StudentWeeklyData AS swd ON s.StudentID = swd.StudentID
WHERE
  s.StudentID = @StudentID
GROUP BY
  s.StudentID,
  s.StudentName,
  swd.WeekNumber
;
```

(Not every detail matters here, I just wanted to use a more similar example for you that would still be simple enough to understand.) Again, this would return only weeks where the specified student has data in `StudentWeeklyTable`. If you wanted to return all weeks for the student (some of them potentially empty, of course), this is how you could go about it:

```
SELECT
  s.StudentID,
  s.StudentName,
  aw.WeekNumber,
  AGG(swd.SomeData)
FROM
  Students AS s
CROSS JOIN
  AllWeeks AS aw
LEFT JOIN
  StudentWeeklyData AS swd ON s.StudentID = swd.StudentID
                          AND aw.WeekNumber = swd.WeekNumber
WHERE
  s.StudentID = @StudentID
GROUP BY
  s.StudentID,
  s.StudentName,
  aw.WeekNumber
;
```

Here you can see again that the `AllWeeks` table is included before the data table. The difference to the previous case is we are not left-joining the result of the join between `Students` and `StudentWeekly` to `AllWeeks`, nor are we left-joining the data table itself specifically to `AllWeeks`. Instead, the data table is joined to the result of a cross join, `Students × AllWeeks`.

Returning to your specific situation, I realise that in your case even more tables are involved. Since you are not specifying how all those tables are related to one another, I can only guess that `SchoolWeekYear` should be cross-joined somewhere after `FROM` and before this line:

```
INNER JOIN Appointment a ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
```

and that the said line should be modified like this:

```
LEFT JOIN Appointment a ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
                       AND swy.calWeekNumber = a.calWeekNumber
```

the `swy` being an alias assigned to `SchoolWeekYear`.

It is also worth noting that there is a subsequent inner join with `AppointmentTherapist`. That join would eliminate the effect of the above left join if it remained unchanged, because its condition references the `Appointment` table. Perhaps, the syntactically easiest way to fix the issue would be to change that inner join to a left one too, although there is another way: instead of

```
LEFT JOIN Appointment a ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
                       AND swy.calWeekNumber = a.calWeekNumber
LEFT JOIN AppointmentTherapist at ON a.appointmentID = at.appointmentID
```

you could use this syntax:

```
LEFT JOIN
    Appointment a
    INNER JOIN AppointmentTherapist at ON a.appointmentID = at.appointmentID
ON as.appointmentID = a.appointmentID
   AND swy.calWeekNumber = a.calWeekNumber
```

That way the logical order of joining would be changed: `Appointment` and `AppointmentTherapist` would be first inner-joined with each other, then *the result set* would be outer-joined to the result of the previously specified joins.

Comment: Wow, Andriy, thank you very much for the explanation. I did consider the syw table needed to be first and I experimented with that but ran into some difficulties. I will work on these recommended changes and let you know.

Comment: Seems like no matter which approach I take, I am getting 52 records without the where clause, but as soon as I add it back in, it limits the record set to the number of records a student had an appointment for.

Comment: Well, if you could set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with data samples to play with...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But if you have multiple row with some `calWeekNumber` on  the `SchoolWeekYear` table, your aggregate function return wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all lines in `SchoolWeekYear` shown, regardless of a match, you should use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of LEFT.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I tried that but it did not work, probably due to where the table is joined in.